# How to use the ChromeApp to connect to a node.js server?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have a Node.js server and I'd like to know how I could do for the ChromeApp to work with it. I tried putting "http://localhost:3000" (server address) on the runtime:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function () {
   chrome.app.window.create('http://localhost:3000');
});
```

But it doesn't even launch. Does someone have an idea on what I could do?
Thanks.

Comment: Place your static content in the app itself and load dynamic data from your webserver via XHR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot launch external URLs with `chrome.app.window.create`. In fact if you check the `chrome.runtime.lastError` property you will see the following error:

> The URL used for window creation must be local for security reasons.

I suggest you look into using the [`<webview>`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) tag as it is much more appropriate for your use-case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I think that for what really I want, I'd need to redo some work, since I wanted to get my Node.js + express server working as an app (I know I wasn't clear in the question).